# get_template_part and template file names

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, get-template-part

I have a custom post type that is going to use a loop in a couple different places and I wanted to make maintaining those loops easier. I remembered that get_template_part() is available and figured this would be an optimal time to get used to it. However, what has me at a standstill is how to set up a file for the loops so that I can call the specific parts accurately.

Google, thus far, has been not helpful in understanding how get_template_part() and twentyten's loop.php actually work and call the 3 parts. I have it duplicated, stripped down and ready for altering for my CPT version, but that is it thus far.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Codex has very decent explanation of [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) logic:

> Assuming the theme folder is
>   wp-content/themes, that the parent
>   theme is twentyten, and the child
>   theme is twentytenchild, then the
>   following code --
>
> ```
> <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
> ```
>
> will do a PHP require() for the named
>   files in this order:
>
> 1. wp-content/themes/twentytenchild/loop-index.php
> 2. wp-content/themes/twentytenchild/loop.php
> 3. wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop-index.php
> 4. wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop.php

Basically you can have more generic templates and more specialized templates. Specialized template is looked up before generic. That is pretty much everything about it.

Comment: thanks for chiming in. After a bit of frustration, i'm just going to do wp_queries instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have always just used it to include files which are within my theme directory.

So, if i have a folder in the theme dir called functions that has a file called utils.php ( wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions/utils.php ) then you can just include the file like so

```
get_template_part( 'functions/utils' ); // includes /functions/utils.php - .php gets added automatically
```

or files in root of theme

```
get_template_part( 'sidebar' ); // includes sidebar.php
```

I don't really get the 2 parameters way of doing it. It works fine for me to just use the dir path structure to files and just leave of the file type.

Comment: I've never tried using a directory there - that's a nifty trick! Thanks for inspiration!